# split a single and specific column into multiple columns every 2 values

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a genotype file with 5 fields (5th field width= 200000 values [zeros and ones]):

```
MA,30009,4,4,000010000111101011111000110100000000 .......
ME,30067,3,2,000010000111101011111000110100000000 .......
MI,30032,7,8,000010000111101011111000110100000000 .......
```

And I want to split the last field into multiple columns every 2 values (ncol = 100000).
I want the output to be as below:

```
MA,30009,4,4,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00 .......
ME,30067,3,2,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00 .......
MI,30032,7,8,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00 .......
```

awk? gwak? sed?

Any help??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub(/../,"&,",$NF)}1' file
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` sets field separators to `,`.
- `{gsub(/../,"&,",$NF)}` appends `,` to every 2 chars in the last field (`$NF`).
- `1` prints the resulting line.

Result:

```
MA,30009,4,4,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00,
```

If you want to remove the trailing comma the above command produces, remove it with an extra `sub` function:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub(/../,"&,",$NF);sub(/,$/,"",$NF)}1' file
```

```
MA,30009,4,4,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Sed with a loop:

```
$ sed -E -e :a -e 's/(,[^,]{2})([^,]{1,})$/\1,\2/;ta' file
MA,30009,4,4,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00
ME,30067,3,2,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00
MI,30032,7,8,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00
```

(I have a feeling there's a neater way to do this, starting from `$` and working backwards - but I can't quite put my finger on it). The `-E` (extended regex) mode is not essential - it just simplifies the escaping.

Alternatively with Perl:

```
$ perl -F, -lne '$last = pop @F; print join ",", @F, $last =~ m/(..)/g' file
MA,30009,4,4,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00
ME,30067,3,2,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00
MI,30032,7,8,00,00,10,00,01,11,10,10,11,11,10,00,11,01,00,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk We merge the last field into the second last and then decrement the field count.

```
gawk -F ',' -v OFS="," '{
  $4 = $4 gensub(/../, ",&", "g", $5)
}NF--' file
```

With awk

```
awk '
  BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," }
  gsub(/../, FS "&", $5) {
    print $1, $2, $3, $4 $5
  }
' file
```

GNU sed with extended mode

```
sed -Ee '
  s/,/\n/4;ta
  :a
    s/\n,/,/;t
    s/..(,..)*$/,&/
  ta
' file
```

Perl where we unpack the field 5th two characters at a  time.

```
perl -F, -lape '$_ = join ",", @F[0..3], unpack "(A2)*", $F[4]' file
```

Another way using Perl

```
perl -F, -lane 'print reverse pop(@F) =~ s/(..)/,$1/gr, join ",", @F' file
```

```
perl -lpe 's/^.*[^,]\K,(.*)/$1 =~ s|(..)|,$1|gr/e' file
```

Using posix sed (\n) on rhs is symbolic. Replace it by an escaped newline)

```
sed -e '
  s/,/\n/4;h;s/\n.*//;x
  s/.*\n//;s/../,&/g;H;x
  s/\n//
' file
```